# Exception while retrieving REMOTE_USER server variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

We have a ashx http handler that retrieves the REMOTE_USER variable from the ServerVariables during the ProcessRequest.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"].Contains("\\")) // exception is thrown here
    ...
```

The authentication is handled by IIS using basic authentication (windows accounts on domain controller).

For some users this starts failing (after working fine for a few hours) and throwing the following exception:

```
[IdentityNotMappedException: Some or all identity references could not be translated.]
   System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceSids, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess) +7608560
   System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier.Translate(Type targetType) +100
   System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetName() +164
   System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_Name() +31
   System.Web.HttpRequest.CalcDynamicServerVariable(DynamicServerVariable var) +8726378
   System.Web.HttpServerVarsCollection.GetSimpleServerVar(String name) +424
   System.Web.HttpServerVarsCollection.Get(String name) +8634072
   System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection.get_Item(String name) +7
   Some.Namespace.AHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\afolder\AHttpHandler.ashx.cs:34
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +181 
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

After we restart the application pool of this application the problem is resolved for about a day.

Any ideas?
Should we use another server variable to retrieve the user name?

Thanks!

Comment: `The authentication is handled by IIS using basic authentication` is that so? But basic authentication is passing username password through HTTP headers. Do you mean `windows authentication`?

Comment: Yes this is basic authentication, which uses a user from the Active Directory: a windows identity.

Answer (score 1):

How about letting the framework do your dirty work for you?

`context.User.Identity.Name` should contain the very same data.